# Magento behaves wierd when setting default view value flag

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I'm currently trying to integrate magento into an erp system.
I wrote for this an connector but having issues in saving data.

This is my code

```
    if(!empty($currentTranslation['products_description']))
    {
        $product->setDescription($currentTranslation['products_description']);
    }
    else
        if(!$default)
    {
        $product->setDescription(false);
    }
    else
    {
        $product->setDescription($primaryDefaultValues['desclong']);
    }
```

(example for setting description)

If I leave a field in for example english unset, it should not set the value.
default is always false for each store view so it sets the description to false.
(I checked this on the double)

If I look at the object just before saving I can see the default Values of the Admin view.
I can also see that the description is set to false.
But when I store the data it sets the default value into the field and does not set the flag use default view.

What am I doing wrong?
I also already tried 0 and null.
But nothing worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
It seemed that I had an issue with the cache system.